# XML Parsing With Perl using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am need to get some values from an XML file...The file is in several sites.. example: http://1.1.1.1/apache2-default/status.xml, http://1.1.1.2/apache2-default/status.xml, etc.. The format for the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gateway>
<version>Kannel bearerbox version `1.4.3' </version>
<status>running, uptime 0d 14h 19m 49s</status>
<wdp>
<received><total>0</total><queued>0</queued></received>
<sent><total>0</total><queued>0</queued></sent>
</wdp>
<sms>
<received><total>50569</total><queued>0</queued></received>
<sent><total>38</total><queued>0</queued></sent>
<storesize>-1</storesize>
<inbound>1.53,1.52,0.98</inbound>
<outbound>0.00,0.00,0.00</outbound>
</sms>
<smscs><count>5</count>
<smsc>
<name>SMPP:1.2.3.4:3802/3802:hng123:HNDSMPP</name>
<id>hng123</id>
<status>online 51589s</status>
<received>0</received>
<sent>0</sent>
<failed>0</failed>
<queued>0</queued>
</smsc>
<smsc>
<name>SMPP:1.2.3.4:3757/3757:vashn:HNDSMPP</name>
<id>vas1</id>
<status>online 51589s</status>
<received>40872</received>
<sent>32</sent>
<failed>0</failed>
<queued>0</queued>
</smsc>
</smscs>
</gateway>
```

Here is the code...that i have created...

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl  -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::Simple;

my $download_dir= "/root/lab_xml_perl/v2/Script_perl/bajados";
my @ips_server = ("192.168.246.129", "192.168.246.130");
for my $servers (@ips_server) {
my $bajo = getstore("http://$servers/apache2-default/status.xml",   "$download_dir/status.xml");

my $file = "$download_dir/status.xml";
my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parsefile($file);

my $root = $twig->root->first_child('smscs');

for my $connection ($root->children){
my $nombre_server = $connection->first_child_text('name');
my $id_server = $connection->first_child_text('id');
my $status_server = $connection->first_child_text('status');
my @status_gral = split(/\s+/, ${status_server});
my $recibidos_msg_server = $connection->first_child_text('received');
my $enviados_msg_server = $connection->first_child_text('sent');
my $encolados_msg_server = $connection->first_child_text('queued');
my $fallidos_msg_server = $connection->first_child_text('failed');
print "miId.String.id = Tabla_$id_server\n";
print "stringProp.String = $nombre_server\n";
print "idProp = $id_server\n";
print "status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = $status_gral[0]\n";
print "recvTotal.Metric = $recibidos_msg_server\n";
print "sentTotal.Metric = $enviados_msg_server\n";
print "queuedTotal.Metric = $encolados_msg_server\n";
print "faildTotal.Metric = $fallidos_msg_server\n";

}
}
```

However when run the script i got some empty fields at the beginning... and a warning... per each xml file from each server....
Here is the output... Why is that?...i do not need them... just need the fields related with the XML..

```
miId.String.id = Tabla_
stringProp.String = 
idProp = 
Use of uninitialized value $status_gral[0] in concatenation (.) or string at ./v25.pl line 32.
status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = 
recvTotal.Metric = 
sentTotal.Metric = 
queuedTotal.Metric = 
faildTotal.Metric = 
miId.String.id = Tabla_hng123
stringProp.String = SMPP:1.2.3.4:3802/3802:hng123:HNDSMPP
idProp = hng123
status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = online
recvTotal.Metric = 0
sentTotal.Metric = 66173
queuedTotal.Metric = 0
faildTotal.Metric = 0 
miId.String.id = Tabla_vas1
stringProp.String = SMPP:1.2.3.4:3757/3757:vashn:HNDSMPP
idProp = vas1
status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = online
recvTotal.Metric = 0
sentTotal.Metric = 45492
queuedTotal.Metric = 0
faildTotal.Metric = 0
Use of uninitialized value $status_gral[0] in concatenation (.) or string at ./v25.pl line 32.
status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = 
recvTotal.Metric = 
sentTotal.Metric = 
queuedTotal.Metric = 
faildTotal.Metric = 
miId.String.id = Tabla_hng123
stringProp.String = SMPP:1.2.3.4:3802/3802:hng123:HNDSMPP
idProp = hng123
status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = online
recvTotal.Metric = 0
sentTotal.Metric = 0
queuedTotal.Metric = 0
faildTotal.Metric = 0
miId.String.id = Tabla_vas1
stringProp.String = SMPP:1.2.3.4:3757/3757:vashn:HNDSMPP
idProp = vas1
status_idObs.StringObservation.obs = online 
recvTotal.Metric = 40872
sentTotal.Metric = 32
queuedTotal.Metric = 0
faildTotal.Metric = 0
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Michael.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the uninitialised value is because the first child in `smscs` is actually `count`.

```
<smscs>
    <count>5</count>
    <smsc>
        <name>SMPP:1.2.3.4:3802/3802:hng123:HNDSMPP</name>
        <id>hng123</id>
        <status>online 51589s</status>
        <received>0</received>
        <sent>0</sent>
        <failed>0</failed>
        <queued>0</queued>
    </smsc>
    <smsc>
        <name>SMPP:1.2.3.4:3757/3757:vashn:HNDSMPP</name>
        <id>vas1</id>
        <status>online 51589s</status>
        <received>40872</received>
        <sent>32</sent>
        <failed>0</failed>
        <queued>0</queued>
    </smsc>
</smscs>
```

So rather than getting all children of `smscs`, you'll need to get only the `smsc` children:

```
foreach my $connection ($root->children('smsc')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: in my experience, `$elt->children()` (or `first_child`, or really any navigation method) is nearly always a bug. You should restrict navigation through the use of a condition, unless you have a really, really, good reason not to do so (and you test the elements you access in the code that follows).

Comment: @mirod what alternative approach would you suggest to navigation using `children`?

Comment: @stevenl the alternative you used: `$root->children('smsc')` ;--) specify what type of child you want, using the tag name or other characteristics, and usually you're fine.